# showGeneralDialog not working as expected

Tags: dart, flutter

Code:

```
void showNow() {
    showGeneralDialog(
      context: context,
      pageBuilder: (BuildContext buildContext, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
        return Container(
          width: 200.0,
          height: 200.0,
          color: Colors.orange,
        ); 
      },
      barrierDismissible: true,
      barrierLabel: MaterialLocalizations.of(context).modalBarrierDismissLabel,
      barrierColor: Colors.black,
      transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
    );
}
```

But this dialog takes up the entire space instead of 200.0 `width` and `height` that I used. I tried wrapping `Container` in `Scaffold`, but then `barrierDismissible` and `barrierColor` doesn't seem to work. I changed their values too but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your Container in Wrap Widget :

```
void showNow() {
    showGeneralDialog(
      context: context,
      pageBuilder: (BuildContext buildContext, Animation<double> animation,
          Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
        return Wrap(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: 200.0,
              height: 200.0,
              color: Colors.orange,
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
      barrierDismissible: true,
      barrierLabel: MaterialLocalizations.of(context).modalBarrierDismissLabel,
      barrierColor: Colors.black,
      transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
    );
  }
```

Comment: It just seems to need a parent widget - not necessarily wrap. Center might make more sense.

Comment: returning `Dialog` as root object is also an option.